# .htaccess rewrite rule to snapshots based on host and request uri

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have the following structure of the platform:

- 1: http://one.domain.com
- 2: http://one.domain.com/welcome - which is the same as the one above
- 3: http://one.domain.com/project/2
- 4: http://domain.com/project/154
- 5: http://two.domain.com/project/26
- etc.

Here the "one" and "two" might be anything.

My goal is to redirect Google crawler to snapshots of the following, which would be:

- For 1: /snapshots/one.domain.com/welcome.html
- For 2: /snapshots/one.domain.com/welcome.html
- For 3: /snapshots/one.domain.com/project/2.html
- For 4: /snapshots/domain.com/project/154.html
- For 5: /snapshots/two.domain.com/project/26.html

For that I'm using .htaccess file and look if `_escaped_fragment_` is present in the query string.

I came up with this to rewrite URLs without any additional URI:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_
RewriteRule ^ /snapshots/%{HTTP_HOST}/welcome.html [NC,L]
```

However, I cannot seem to get the one with request URI provided to work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?(.*)$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_
RewriteRule ^ /snapshots/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]
```

I believe I'm very close, but something is missing...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^ /snapshots/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]` Remove the extra / between `HTTP_HOST` and `REQUEST_URI`. I tested it and it worked http://htaccess.mwl.be/

Comment: Thanks, only ? had to be added after ".html" to prevent loop.